# list index out of range

Tags: python, list

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
from os import path

input = open('/home/XXXXXX/ERR001268_1', 'r').read().split('\n')

at = 1
for lines in range(0, len(input)):
    line1 = input[lines]
    line4 = input[lines+3]
    num1 = line1.split(':')[4].split()[0]
    num4 = line4.split(':')[4].split()[0]
    print num1,num4


    at += 1
```

However I got the error: list index out of range

What's the problem here?

btw, besides `"at +=1"`, is there any other way to finish this cycle loop?
thx

Comment: What does `at` doing there anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say `len(input) == 10`. `range(0, len(input))` iterates `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. And when lines > 6 and you're trying to access `input[lines+3`], it clearly an IndexError, because there is no `index[10]`, `[11]` etc .

And `line1.split(':')[4]` can also raise an IndexError if `line1.count(":") < 4`.

I didn't understand the last `at` part, it seems not doing anything, but you can break the loop easily with `break` statement.

Also, naming a variable `input` is a bad idea because it conflicts with builtin `input` function. And `range(0, len(input)) == range(len(input))`, so 0 as range's first argument is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `lines` has a maximum value of `len(input)-1` but then you let `line4` be `lines + 3`. So, when you're at your last couple of lines, `lines + 3` will be larger than the length of the list.

```
for lines in range(0, len(input)):
    line1 = input[lines]
    line4 = input[lines+3]
    num1 = line1.split(':')[4].split()[0]
    num4 = line4.split(':')[4].split()[0]
    print num1,num4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to read a file and get some info from it every 3 lines. I would recommend something simpler:

```
def get_num(line):
    return line.split(':')[4].split()[0]

nums1 = [get_num(l) for l in open(fn, "r").readlines()]
nums2 = nums1[3:]
for i in range(len(nums2)):
    print nums1[i],nums2[i]
```

The last 3 numbers of nums1 won't be written. The variable at does not do anything in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and here is the solution I came up with:

```
tuple = (1,2,3)

dogs = [ ]

cats = [ ]

one_two = [ ]

cats.apend(tuple)

dogs.apend(tuple)

file.apend(one_two)

file.apend("/")

print file
print cats
print dogs
```

Have an excellent day.