# Python:Getting list index out of range error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Getting list index out of range error in line amount=int(values[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me3Bi.png)),as far as I can see ,I am not violating any index ranges.
I have checked these 
[Python error - list index out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845247/python-error-list-index-out-of-range)
[List index out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802624/list-index-out-of-range)
[list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033192/list-index-out-of-range)
but they are of not much use.

```
netAmount = 0
while True:
    s = raw_input()
    if not s:
        break
    values = s.split(" ")
    operation = values[0]
    amount = int(values[1])  
    if operation=="D":
        netAmount+=amount
    elif operation=="W":
        netAmount-=amount
    else:
        pass

print netAmount
```

**edited-After printing after the split method 
print is working fine but error still persists
[image: Output]

Comment: can you use `print values` after `vaues = s.split(" ")` and share the result. Also do the same for `amount`

Comment: What input are you giving? Something that has more than one word should work.

Comment: What input to ``raw_input`` is giving you the error? At glance you would type ``D 10`` or ``W 20`` and it should work.

Comment: While I am giving input 0 to terminate the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the test before the split to avoid accessing the list out of range:

```
netAmount = 0
while True:
    s = raw_input()
    if not s or s=="0":
        break
    values = s.split(" ")
    operation = values[0]
    amount = int(values[1])
    if operation=="D":
        netAmount+=amount
    elif operation=="W":
        netAmount-=amount
    else:
        pass

print netAmount
```

Comment: Why not s and s=="0" are not the same thing

Comment: okay,I get it now ,actually I had worked on C/C++ earlier so I was drawing analogy from that.